# what jvm do with marker interface in java

Tags: java, serialization, jvm, marker-interfaces

As question said what JVM gives extra treatment to classes implementing Marker interface .
For example I have test it using Serializable like below:

import java.io.*;

```
public class SerialazationDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //serialized object
/*      Employee e = new Employee();
        e.name = "Reyan Ali";
        e.address = "Phokka Kuan, Ambehta Peer";
        e.SSN = 11122333;
        e.number = 101;
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("E:\\temp\\employee.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(e);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in /tmp/employee.ser");
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        //deserialized object
         Employee e = null;
          try
          {
             FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("E:\\temp\\employee.ser");
             ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
             e = (Employee) in.readObject();
             in.close();
             fileIn.close();
          }catch(IOException i)
          {
             i.printStackTrace();
             return;
          }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
          {
             System.out.println("Employee class not found");
             c.printStackTrace();
             return;
          }
          System.out.println("Deserialized Employee...");
          System.out.println("Name: " + e.name);
          System.out.println("Address: " + e.address);
          System.out.println("SSN: " + e.SSN);
          System.out.println("Number: " + e.number);
    }
}

class Employee {
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public transient int SSN;
    public int number;

    public void mailCheck() {
        System.out.println("Mailing a check to " + name + " " + address);
    }
}
```

And i found that jvm gives exception as java.io.NotSerializableException But FILES was created on given path, similar exception for deserialization. So why JVM required it to be serialized , It could directly allow creating a serialization.?

Comment: You seem to be asking three questions at the same time: what does the JVM do with marker interfaces? why was the file created? why isn't everything `Serializable?`

Answer (score 4):

> question said what JVM gives extra treatment to classes implementing Marker interface

The correct answer to that question is *nothing.* But it probably requires eludication, as the questioner may be using terms imprecisely.

The ***JRE*** treats them specially in appropriate places. This action is located in the Java Class Library, not in the JVM. For example:

- `Object.clone()` tests that the object implements `Cloneable.`
- `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` tests that the object being written implements `Serializable.`
- `rmic` and parts of the RMI runtime test that a remote object implements a remote interface, which means an interface that extends `Remote.`

This has nothing to do with the JVM *per se.*

> I found that jvm gives exception as java.io.NotSerializableException

No you didn't. You found that `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` threw an exception. It isn't the same thing.

> But FILES was created on given path

The file was created by `new FileOutputStream(...),` which had already executed before you got the exception.

> So why JVM required it to be serialized , It could directly allow creating a serialization.?

It doesn't. See above. But `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` does, and it does so because making everything `Serializable` has numerous disadvantages that need to be considered before you suggest it. Consider for example the security risk of a serializable password field that you didn't intend.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're required to extend `Serializable` (or `Externalizable`) is to ensure that you're only serialising classes that are *designed* for serialisation. You certainly don't want to serialise classes that aren't designed for it, because then their format would be quite fragile; the smallest change to the class would break your deserialisation.

One could argue that the same fragility applies to classes marked `Serializable`, but you're supposed to think about serial form stability when marking a class as `Serializable` (or else explicitly disavow any stability, as Guava does).

Answer (score 0):

If the object is not `Serializable` its state cannot be saved using `ObjectOutputStrem`.

File must be created because that is done using `FileInputStream` and as soon as you close the stream, there will be a new file. But if try to check the contents of the file, it should be empty, because the state of non-serializable state will not be saved.

Answer (score 0):

What is a Marker Interface?

An interface is called a marker interface when it is provided as a
 handle by java interpreter to mark a class so that it can provide
 special behaviour to it at runtime and they do not have any method
 declarations

Marker interface just marks a class as being of a particular type.

Why marker Interface is required?

Marker interface is used as a tag to inform a message to the java
 compiler so that it can add special behaviour to the class
 implementing it.So if JVM sees a Class is Serializable it done some
 special operation on it

What JVM does with Serialiize Interface?

When a class implements serializable interface it assures JVM that
 this class may provide a special
 behavior(Serialization/Deserialization) at run time.

So when you are trying to serialize object JVM wants to confirm that whether class of object of this type has made a contract(Implementing Serialize interface) to show this special behavior at runtime(To be serialize/deserialized).If it has implemented,JVM is assured that it can proceed further for serialization Otherwise it throws exception that you are trying to serialize an object  that  does't agree to terms and condition of being ready for serialization or deserialization.

Comment: You can't use an annotation for `Serializable,` or `Cloneable`, or `Remote,` no doubt many others.

Comment: @EJP : I just said that about Marker Interface.

Comment: The three I mentioned are all marker interfaces. The need for them is not eliminated. You need to qualify your remark.

Comment: @EJP : I will remove that note from answer :)

Comment: Good idea. It wasn't relevant anyway, also dubious. I don't find annotations any more convenient, unless there is already an annotation-processing framework in place. Writing the code to detect an annotation is 10x as complex as `instanceof`.

Comment: The compiler does not add any special behaviour to the class when it implements a marker interface. It all happens at runtime.